# Find the minimum distance beween 2 nodes

Tags: java

Can anyone help me figure it out how to solve my problem. I need to find the shortest path between 2 given nodes. So far I have managed to save all posible paths in a list, and now I'm trying to find the minimal distance.
here is my code:

```
public class A {
    private static int[][] adjacency = new int [6][6];
    static int n = 6;
    private static final int START = 1;
    private static final int END = 4;

    private Map<Integer, LinkedHashSet<Integer>> map = new HashMap();
    private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> pathsFound = new HashMap();

    public void addEdge(int node1, int node2) {
        LinkedHashSet<Integer> adjacent = map.get(node1);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            adjacent = new LinkedHashSet();
            map.put(node1, adjacent);
        }
        adjacent.add(node2);
    }

    public LinkedList<Integer> adjacentNodes(Integer last) {
        LinkedHashSet<Integer> adjacent = map.get(last);
        if(adjacent==null) {
            return new LinkedList();
        }
        return new LinkedList<Integer>(adjacent);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList<Integer> visited = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        visited.add(START);
        A graph = new A();

        for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
                adjacency[i][j] = 0;    
        adjacency[0][1] = 1;
        adjacency[0][2] = 2;
        adjacency[1][0] = 1;
        adjacency[1][3] = 5;
        adjacency[1][4] = 9;
        adjacency[1][5] = 6;
        adjacency[2][0] = 2;
        adjacency[2][4] = 7;
        adjacency[2][5] = 2;
        adjacency[3][1] = 5;
        adjacency[4][1] = 9;
        adjacency[4][2] = 7;
        adjacency[4][5] = 1;
        adjacency[5][1] = 6;
        adjacency[5][2] = 2;
        adjacency[5][4] = 1;

        graph.addEdge(0,1);
        graph.addEdge(0,2);
        graph.addEdge(1,0);
        graph.addEdge(1,3);
        graph.addEdge(1,4);
        graph.addEdge(1,5);
        graph.addEdge(2,0);
        graph.addEdge(2,4);
        graph.addEdge(2,5);
        graph.addEdge(3,1);
        graph.addEdge(4,1);
        graph.addEdge(4,2);
        graph.addEdge(4,5);
        graph.addEdge(5,1);
        graph.addEdge(5,2);
        graph.addEdge(5,4);

        graph.breadthFirst(visited);
    }

    public void breadthFirst(LinkedList<Integer> visited) {
    LinkedList<Integer> nodes = adjacentNodes(visited.getLast());
    List<List<Integer>> allPaths = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> distances = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node)) 
            continue;
        if (node == END) {
            visited.add(node);
            List<Integer> path = getPath(visited);
            System.out.println(path);
            ??allPaths.add(path);
            visited.removeLast();
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int node : nodes) {
        if (visited.contains(node) || node == END) 
            continue;
        visited.addLast(node);
        breadthFirst(visited);
        visited.removeLast();
    }
    System.out.println(allPaths.get(0));

   }


        public static List<Integer> getPath(LinkedList<Integer> visited) {  
        List<Integer> path = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int node : visited)
            path.add(node);
        return path;    
        }

}
```

If I do like this `System.out.println(path);` it prints the path, which means that the function `getPath()` works. 
But when I want to put this path in a list : `allPaths.add(path);` something goes wrong, because when I call after the for loop end `System.out.println(allPaths.get(0));` I get an `IndexOutOfBoundException`. I really don't understand why my `allPaths` list is empty...

Comment: You might want to read into djikstra's algorithm for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Definitely check out some of the algorithms.

As to why you're getting an IndexOutOfBoundException, it's because on the third pass through breadthFirst you have no elements in distances. Throw your code into an IDE and step through the code with a debugger, or just wrap that addition into a check for an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you iterate with a foreach ?

```
for (int number : arrlist) {
    System.out.println("Number = " + number);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Don't you said the for to get min distances crash your app ?

Comment: Actually what crashes the app is this min=distances.get(0). It seems that there is nothing. I don't understand why my distances is empty

Comment: Starting my laptop, ill try it

Comment: Ok, meanwhile I will keep try to fix it

Comment: Can't even understand your algorithm x).
Comment your code while writing it, especially is someone is supposed to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps invoking the last snippet (in your question) *before* you have filled in the distances collection? You need to invoke it afterwards, not before.

[Aside: In the future, if you have an exception, you really need to provide the exception message and stack trace. Makes helping you much easier...]